# Resource is not available in rest web application

Tags: rest, jsp, tomcat7

I'm working on rest web application project , but I'm not able to access any html or jsp files of my application while the rest call's are working fine .
Below is web.xml

```html
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>User Management</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.ali</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and for test purpose  I have created below  hello.jsp and kept under Webcontent of my project

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Hello World - JSP tutorial</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= "Hello World!" %>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Here is my UserManagement project   [Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiHgd.jpg)

So can someone let me know where I'm going wrong and why I'm getting resource not available error every time when I'm trying to access html or jsp .

Thanks  in Advance ,
Ali .

Answer (score 0):

some modification needed in web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>hello.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

now call your project with project url